# ¿Cómo mostrar 3 listview en un layout android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

quisiera mostrar 3 listview uno al lado del otro parecido a la imagen de abajo y se deslize horizontalmente para ver los demás listview.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Encabezado"
                    android:textSize="18dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        >

                    </ListView>


                </LinearLayout>






        </LinearLayout>




    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView lstDias;
    Button btnPostYourEnquiry;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lstDias = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        ArrayList<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<>();
        listaNombres.add("Juan");
        listaNombres.add("Juan");
        listaNombres.add("Juan");
        listaNombres.add("Juan");



        ArrayAdapter adapter =  new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaNombres);
        lstDias.setAdapter(adapter);


        FrameLayout footerLayout = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer,null);
        btnPostYourEnquiry = (Button) footerLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnGetMoreResults);
        lstDias.addFooterView(footerLayout);

    }
}
```

footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnGetMoreResults"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:text="Agregar"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: El primer layout debería tener una posición horizontal android:orientation="horizontal", y luego, dentro de éste, puedes meter los otros 3 en vertical

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que quieres que los 3 tengan el mismo tamaño solo debes incluirlos en un `LinearLayout` con orientacion horizontal

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Solo se muestra un listview